# Support for Authenticated Proxy in google-http-client java library

Tags: google-api, google-http-client

We are using NetHttpTransport provided by google-http-client java library, which allows us to [specify a proxy](https://cloud.google.com/java/docs/reference/google-http-client/latest/com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport.Builder#com_google_api_client_http_javanet_NetHttpTransport_Builder_setProxy_java_net_Proxy_). However, I could not figure out a way to specify the username and password. For Http proxies, we could provide it using "Proxy-Authorization" headers. But we need to use this for a SOCKS proxy. Is there any support for this ?